# How can I populate dropdown values dynamically based on prior selection?

Tags: javascript, object, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dropdowns with some values. I am using JavaScript to pre-populate the first dropdown.

Based on the selected value in 1st dropdown, how can I populate values in the rest 2 dropdowns (using pure javascript)?

I am framing a URL based on the user selected values in 3 dropdowns using `function getURL` ,but unable to capture the prepopluated product Name in the URL. Why is it showing the value of `ProductName` as `undefined`?

[image]

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
var ProductNameMap = {
        "ProductA":[{"version":"1.0.0","fileName":"FileA1.zip","fileName":"FileA11.dmg"},{"version":"1.0.1","fileName":"FileA2.zip","fileName":"FileA22.dmg"}],
        "ProductB":[{"version":"3.5.0","fileName":"FileB1.zip","fileName":"FileB11.dmg"},{"version":"4.0.1","fileName":"FileB2.zip","fileName":"FileB21.dmg"}], 
        "ProductC":[{"version":"1.0.0","fileName":"FileC1.zip","fileName":"FileC11.dmg"},{"version":"1.0.1","fileName":"FileC2.zip","fileName":"FileC21.dmg"}]   
};

function PrepopulateProductName()
    {
        var ProductNameselect = document.getElementById('selProductName');
        var i=1;
        for (selProductName in ProductNameMap){
          ProductNameselect.options[i++] = new Option(selProductName)
        }
    }
function changeProductName(productNameID)
    {
      //Need to populate version dropdown of selected Product
}
function changeProductVersion(productVersionID)
    {
 //Need to populate file name dropdown of selected ProductVersion
    }


    function getURL() {

        var url = "http://abc.def.com";
        var pnid = (selProductName  == "") ? "0" : selProductName.value;
        var psid = (selProductVersion.value == "") ? "0" : selProductVersion.value;
        var pfid = (selFileName.value == "") ? "0" : selFileName.value;

        url += "/" + pnid;
        url += "/" + psid;
        url += "/" + pfid;

        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Download Link : ";
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").innerHTML = url;
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = url;
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").target = "_blank";
    }

</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
Product Name:
<select id="selProductVersion" name="selProductVersion" 
        onchange="changeProductName(this.value);">
<option>--Choose Product Name--</option>
</select>

Product Version:
    <select id="selProductVersion" name="selProductVersion" 
        onchange="changeProductVersion(this.value);">
    </select>           

File Name:
<select id="selFileName" name="selFileName"></select>

<button onclick="getURL()">Get URL</button>
<p id="text"></p>
<a id="myAnchor"></a>
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `javascript:` prefix in `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed in attributes that contain URLs (e.g. `href`), not scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array of details for the product name to get the versions.

The `filename` property should be an array so you can have multiple files for each version.

```js
var ProductNameMap = {
  "ProductA": [{"version": "1.0.0", "fileName": ["FileA1.zip", "FileA11.zip"]}, {"version": "1.0.1", "fileName": ["FileA2.zip", "FileA22.zip"]}],
  "ProductB": [{"version": "3.5.0", "fileName": ["FileB1.zip", "FileB11.zip"]}, {"version": "4.0.1", "fileName": ["FileB2.zip", "FileB22.zip"]}],
  "ProductC": [{"version": "1.0.0", "fileName": ["FileC1.zip", "FileC11.zip"]}, {"version": "1.0.1", "fileName": ["FileC2.zip", "FileC22.zip"]}]
};

function PrepopulateProductName() {
  var ProductNameselect = document.getElementById('selProductName');
  var i = 1;
  for (var selProductName in ProductNameMap) {
    ProductNameselect.options[i++] = new Option(selProductName)
  }
}

function changeProductName(productNameID) {
  var versionSelect = document.getElementById('selProductVersion');
  versionSelect.innerHTML = '<option>--Choose Product Version</option>'; // Remove previous options
  var fileSelect = document.getElementById('selFileName');
  fileSelect.innerHTML = '<option>--Choose Filename</option>'; // Remove previous options
  var versions = ProductNameMap[productNameID];
  for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
    versionSelect.appendChild(new Option(versions[i].version));
  }
}

function changeProductVersion(productVersion) {
  var productNameID = document.getElementById('selProductName').value;
  var fileSelect = document.getElementById('selFileName');
  fileSelect.innerHTML = ''; // Remove previous options
  var versions = ProductNameMap[productNameID];
  for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
    if (versions[i].version == productVersion) {
      var filenames = versions[i].fileName;
      for (var j = 0; j < filenames.length; j++) {
        fileSelect.appendChild(new Option(filenames[j]));
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}


PrepopulateProductName();
```

```html
Product Name:
<select id="selProductName" name="selProductName" onchange="changeProductName(this.value);">
  <option>--Choose Product Name--</option>
</select>
<br>Product Version:
<select id="selProductVersion" name="selProductVersion" onchange="changeProductVersion(this.value);">
</select>
<br>File Name:
<select id="selFileName" name="selFileName"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There can be multiple `filenames` sometimes. I have updated my data `ProductNameMap ` with few instances of multiple filenames. I have tried `function changeProductVersion` similar to your answer to display respective `File Name` for selected `Product Version`. But its not working. Updated the above code snippet with the function I tried. What am I missing in `function changeProductVersion` to display File Name(s)

Comment: An object can't have multiple properties with the same key, as you have shown in your edit. You should make `filename` an array of all the filenames. Then you can use a `for` loop in `changeProductVersion` similar to the one in `changeProductName`.

Comment: But how can I associate my `filenames` array for every specific `product & version`. Because there can be multiple `Products` with same `versions` like `ProductA` and `ProductC`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanationa nd answer. It worked. But I have added a buttoon in html to frame a URL based on the user selected values in 3 dropdowns using `function getURL` ,but unable to capture the prepopluated product Name in the URL. Why is it showing the value of `ProductName` as `undefined`? I have updated my earlier question,code and screenshot as well with this issue also to be clear  for people referring to it.

Comment: You never set the values of `selProductName`, `selProductVersion`, and `selFileName`.